# Etiqueta meta - viewport para responsive designe

Tags: html, viewport, meta-tags

Quisiera saber si los parámetros en **negrita** aún son válidos, ya que en el visual studio code al ingresar "meta:vp" no me los da automáticamente y necesito agregarlo manualmente.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, **user-scalable=no**, initial-scale=1.0, **maximun-scale=1.0**, **minimum-scale=1.0**">
```

¿O será que ya no es necesario agregarlos?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con la especificación oficial de la **W3C**<sup>1</sup> las propiedades reconocidas para el `meta` donde se declara el `viewport` son:

- width
- height
- initial-scale
- maximum-scale
- minimum-sacle
- user-scalable

Cada uno de los anteriores tiene una finalidad y motivo de existir específico; por ejemplo:

Una existen para indicar como es que el usuario va poder o no manipular el zoom que se le permita hacerle al viewport de la página web cuando apenas cargue y otras veces cuando ya cargo por completo; **entonces son válidas, opcionales y no estrictamente necesarias dependiendo de lo que buscas o no implementar**.

Nota:

Si el plugin que uses no lo muestra es por que por *default* tal vez no lo incluya

**Referencias**

- [Doc. oficial de la W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#viewport-meta)